# amazon-cognito-vuex-module login throws User is not authorized to get auth details

Tags: amazon-web-services, vue.js, amazon-cognito, vuex

I am trying authentication using amazon-cognito-vuex-module package

https://github.com/Botre/amazon-cognito-vuex-module

Following is my code for cognito configuration:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    auth,
    cognito: new AmazonCognitoVuexModule({
      region: 'us-east-1',
      userPoolId: '<myPoolId>',
      clientId: '<myClientId>'
    })
  },
  strict: debug
})
```

and this is how I am trying authenticating user:

```
this.$store.dispatch('authenticateUser', { email: this.input.username, password: this.input.password })
```

**authenticateUser** function is as follows:

```
authenticateUser ({ commit, state }, payload) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      commit('setAuthenticating', true)
      const email = payload.email
      const password = payload.password
      const user = new CognitoUser({
        Username: email,
        Pool: state.pool
      })
      user.authenticateUser(
        new AuthenticationDetails({
          Username: email,
          Password: password
        }),
        {
          onFailure: function (error) {
            commit('setAuthenticating', false)
            reject(error)
          },
          onSuccess: function (session) {
            commit('setAuthenticating', false)
            commit('setAuthenticated', user)
            resolve(session)
          },
          newPasswordRequired: function (userAttributes, requiredAttributes) {
            commit('setAuthenticating', false)
            delete userAttributes.email_verified // Immutable field
            user.completeNewPasswordChallenge(
              payload.newPassword,
              userAttributes,
              this
            )
          }
        }
      )
    })
  }
```

Getting following error in response:

> {"__type":"NotAuthorizedException","message":"User is not authorized
>   to get auth details."}